# Is there a way to create different type but same base inheritance objects defined in a shared library?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a shared library to use for some of my projects. The idea is to contain all classes that I use for a generic role, in this case file I/O, with an API and create instances of derived classes tailored to specific tasks. The problem is that I can't create the different instances from the different derived classes. The compiler throws errors of "multiple definition of BaseFile::create(FileObjectType)" and "multiple definition of BaseFile::destroy(BaseFile*)"

I work with linux, and Code::Blocks. I have made a header file where the API (the base class where all others inherit from) and two functions, one to create and return an instance, and one to destroy it. At a second header file, I keep the class declarations and the implementation of the member functions create and destroy, and multiple files where I implement each class.

```
//This is the API header file
#ifndef FILELIB_HPP_INCLUDED
#define FILELIB_HPP_INCLUDED
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
//The different classes available, that inherit the base class
enum FileObjectType {
    FOT_OUTFILE, FOT_OUTFILEB, FOT_INFILE, FOT_INFILEB
};
//The base class
class BaseFile {
protected:
    string sFileName;
    int iSize;
    fstream FileStream;
public:
    virtual bool bOpenFile(string FileName);
    virtual string sReturnBlock(int IndexNumber, int BlockSize);
    virtual bool bAppendBlock(string BlockToWrite);
    virtual bool bCreateFile(string FileName);
        virtual void vCloseFile();
        //The two functions that return 
        static BaseFile* create(FileObjectType);
        static void destroy(BaseFile* prt);
    BaseFile() {};
    virtual ~BaseFile();
};
//The two functions to be exported
extern "C" BaseFile* create(FileObjectType eType);
extern "C" void destroy(BaseFile* ptr);

#endif // FILELIB_HPP_INCLUDED
```

The main header file where I keep the declarations:

```
//The header file where I keep the declarations
#ifndef MAINHEADER_HPP_INCLUDED
#define MAINHEADER_HPP_INCLUDED
#include "FileLib.hpp"
#include <iostream>
//Each specialised class declarations
class OutFile : public BaseFile {
private:
public:
    OutFile();
    ~OutFile();
};
class OutFileb : public BaseFile {
private:
public:
    OutFileb();
    ~OutFileb();
};
class InFileb : public BaseFile {
private:
public:
    InFileb();
    ~InFileb();
};
class InFile : public BaseFile {
private:
public:
    InFile();
    ~InFile();
};
//The two functions-to-be-exported implementation
BaseFile* BaseFile::create(FileObjectType eType)
{
    if (eType == FOT_OUTFILE) return new OutFile;
    if (eType == FOT_OUTFILEB) return new OutFileb;
    if (eType == FOT_INFILE) return new InFile;
    if (eType == FOT_INFILEB) return new InFileb;
    return NULL;
}
void BaseFile::destroy(BaseFile* ptr)
{
    delete ptr;
    return;
}
#endif // MAINHEADER_HPP_INCLUDED
```

The error of multiple definitions says that the functions create and destroy were first defined here. **I've tried to declare those functions outside the BaseFile class, as standalone functions, but the same error remains.**

The implementation files contain the #include for the main header file, the empty implementations of the derived classes' constructors and destructors, and nothing else. I tried to implement the factory method. Thank you for your time.

Edit: The compiler's exact errors: (Apologies but the text dump site doesn't work, so I'll dump it here too) https://pastebin.com/ZGXNBQhW

```
-------------- Build: Debug in FileLib (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu obj/Debug/InFile.o obj/Debug/InFileb.o obj/Debug/main.o obj/Debug/OutFileb.o -o bin/Debug/libFileLib.so
obj/Debug/InFileb.o: In function `OutFile::~OutFile()':
/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:42: multiple definition of `BaseFile::create(FileObjectType)'
obj/Debug/InFile.o:/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:42: first defined here
obj/Debug/InFileb.o: In function `BaseFile::destroy(BaseFile*)':
/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:50: multiple definition of `BaseFile::destroy(BaseFile*)'
obj/Debug/InFile.o:/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:50: first defined here
obj/Debug/main.o: In function `OutFile::~OutFile()':
/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:42: multiple definition of `BaseFile::create(FileObjectType)'
obj/Debug/InFile.o:/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:42: first defined here
obj/Debug/main.o: In function `BaseFile::destroy(BaseFile*)':
/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:50: multiple definition of `BaseFile::destroy(BaseFile*)'
obj/Debug/InFile.o:/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:50: first defined here
obj/Debug/OutFileb.o: In function `OutFile::~OutFile()':
/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:42: multiple definition of `BaseFile::create(FileObjectType)'
obj/Debug/InFile.o:/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:42: first defined here
obj/Debug/OutFileb.o: In function `BaseFile::destroy(BaseFile*)':
/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:50: multiple definition of `BaseFile::destroy(BaseFile*)'
obj/Debug/InFile.o:/home/myuser/Projects/FileLib/MainHeader.hpp:50: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
12 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: Where are the functions defined second? What other definitions does the compiler point to? Show the exact and complete text of the error messages.

Comment: The functions create and destroy are not defined anywhere else at all the files. My guess is that it may be some inheritance auto-define thing, that carries on to all derived classes and the compiler counts that as multiple defines.

Comment: Your link does not seem to be working, could you please update it? Little side note: Don't use `using namespace std;` in header files. - **Still not working after your edit.**

Comment: Some more comments on the code (since it's tagged C++11): You should use smart pointers instead of raw pointers whenever possible (your code is a typical use case). Have a look at `unique_ptr`. Don't define default constructors/destructors unless you have to. Consider defining `default` ctors if required. Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Declare - don't define - functions in headers.

Comment: My thanks to everyone for all feedback and advice. The problem was solved when I moved the functions' implementation to a source file, and made them standalone instead of static member functions in the base class. Let's hope this actually works as intended, but for now it compiles!